# Just found that pressing "R" opens the achievements toolbar. Improve UI around shortcuts discoverability

Tags: feature-request, keyboard-shortcuts

I propose that we add, somewhere in the UI, some indication that there are keyboard shortcuts. This will likely improve the chance that someone will know of their existence and benefit from them.

Ideally, I should not have to search somewhere about keyboard shortcuts to know that they exist in the first place.

One suggestion: on the help button on top right, add a new section "keyboard shortcuts". When pressed, the shortcuts to access each part of the UI are shown overlayed on the website, showing how to access each of the components through them.

Another suggestion: when a user reaches X reputation, add it as a functionality to the user (with a respective indication on the promotion).  This avoids new users being overwhelmed by new features on the start, and at the same time increases exposure of this functionality when users become more used to the website.

I am not expert in UX, so I am not the best person to provide solutions. Still, my main point is that keyboard shortcuts are difficult to find/know about their existence.

Comment: Worth noting that you must go into your profile and activate keyboard shortcuts for them to work, otherwise nothing will happen when people press "R", go here to turn them on: https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current

Comment: Typical case of having enabled a feature, totally forgot about it and now ask the site to refresh your and our memory ...  we need Clippy back: *Hey, I see you haven't used the keyboard shortcuts for a while, need some help?* ... ;)

Comment: Pressing `?` (on a US keyboard, Shift + `/`) will show a popup with all available shortcuts. If only *that* would somehow become discoverable...